# Cannot use %install in Swift Colab

Tags: swift, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I try to install a new library in Swift on Google Colab

```
%install '.package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueCryptor.git", from: "1.0.28")' Cryptor
```

Then, there is an error

```
...
error: toolchain is invalid: could not find the `swiftc` at expected path /swift/toolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
Install Error: swift-build returned nonzero exit code 1.
```

But I check that `swiftc` does exist in `/swift/toolchain/usr/bin`.
Here's a [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1006N3eJ1YP3NzWBe3-jN17C8judfHyZJ)
that demonstrate the error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Now I update it to the latest Swift version. By running this notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/notebooks/install_latest_swift.ipynb

There's no error anymore. So, just need to update it.

You can also do it all from the Swift notebook as well, using this code.

```swift
import Python
Python.import("subprocess").getoutput("""
rm -rf /swift
mkdir -p /swift/toolchain
wget -nv -O- https://storage.googleapis.com/s4tf-kokoro-artifact-testing/latest/swift-tensorflow-DEVELOPMENT-cuda10.0-cudnn7-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz | tar xzf - -C /swift/toolchain
wget -nv -O- https://storage.googleapis.com/s4tf-kokoro-artifact-testing/latest/swift-jupyter.tar.gz | tar xzf - -C /swift
python3 /swift/swift-jupyter/register.py --swift-toolchain /swift/toolchain
apt-get install libblocksruntime-dev
""")
```